# Best Approach to Series of Events - Sold as a Package

Tags: civievent, repeating-events

We have a 5 week series of classes - we wanted one purchase to register the attendee for all 5 weeks with one purchase.  We created a repeating event, but we were unable to turn off registration for events 2-5. What we ended up doing was creating the first event as the main event then created a duplicate repeating events with registration off, linking them all to the main event in the description.

While it has been suggested to just list the dates in the description and have the event span the weeks that the event takes place. That does not meet our needs. We want to be able to track attendees per event. For now, we will just upload the registrants to the other events and mark the attendees.

Wordpress and CiviCRM Latest

Comment: What CMS? If Drupal I can explain how to do via Webform

Comment: Exactly - that’s how!

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Wordpress :-/

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT Well then - we figured that out. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the price of the event is the same, regardless the classes the participant wants to attend. You can extend the participation with a custom field that registers to register the classes.

Comment: I give this a tick as I understand you to say, use a single event, add a custom field to those Participants which has eg 5 tickboxes, one for each of the weeks, then you can just record who attended probably by using a simple Batch Update via Profile. Nice. Thanks. THat got me out of a bad approach of multiple linked events.

Comment: If that wasn't what you meant I will paste mine as separate Answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

We have done some work on an [extension](https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.multipleeventreg) which gives a UI as a custom event field where you can select the 'other' events that should be registered for along with the parent one. Works eg for a Series where you want user registered for each event separately, but for a single fee, but eg then allows for flexibility of recording that participant didn't show up on Week 3 Monday series and instead took a spare spot on the Week 3 Thursday series so they didn't miss out on a week.